# Lollipop only crash "Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v7/appcompat/R$styleable"

Tags: android, crash, android-5.0-lollipop, android-appcompat

I get this crash in Lollipop only, when I launch my app. Other versions work fine, e.g. 4.4

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v7/appcompat/R$styleable;
```

[image: pic1]

[image: pic1]

what is wrong?

**EDIT1:**

```
android:minSdkVersion="8"
android:targetSdkVersion="22"
```

values/styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/EditTextStyle</item>

</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
</style>
<style name="EditTextStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.EditText"/>
</resources>
```

values-v21/styles.xml:

```
<resources>
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
</style>
</resources>
```

Comment: What `style.xml` do you have?

Comment: What are your minSdk and targetSdk?

Comment: You are using a AppCompat theme so you should remove android from the namespace inside your theme in values-v21

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti yeah, but AppCompat is a backport of some features for android < 5, so in android >= 5 it runs natively, so there has to be 'android' tag, right?

Comment: @Gintas_ No. It doesn't require a values-v21 style or the android namespsace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a AppCompat theme so you should remove android from the namespace inside your theme in values-v21

Also it doesn't require a values-v21 style.

Comment: How does then look values-v21?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using the AppCompat library from the Android SDK directory.
Just make a copy of the library folder and put it near your project, then re-import it to Eclipse from the new location.